# Superposition question given two diffeq's

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

So I go this problem:
$\ y1[t]\text{ solves }
       y^\prime[t]+9.7 y[t]= e^{-0.4t} \cos[t],\text{ with } y[0]=0,$

and

$$y2[t]\text{ solves }
       y^\prime[t]+9.7 y[t]=0,\text{ with } y[0]=1.
$$

What numbers $p$ and $q$ do you pick to make
$$y[t]=p y1[t] + q y2[t]$$

solve
$$
y^\prime[t]+9.7 y[t]=3 e^{-0.4 t} \cos[t],\text{ with } y[0]=3\text{?}
$$
I found that:
$$
\ y1[t] = 0.0980487e^{-9.7t} (1 + \sin(t) + \cos(t))
$$
and
$$
\ y2[t] = e^{-9.7}
$$
I tried solving $y[t]$ and getting two equations but keep getting stuck on how to find $p$ and $q$ ...any hints :) ?

Answer (score 1):

(This should be a comment, but for some strange reason I'm suddenly unable to make a comment)

First of all, the question is stated wrong: either there should be $e^{-.4 t} \cos(t)$ and $3 e^{-.4 t} \cos(t)$, or $e^{-.4 t} + \cos(t)$ and $3 (e^{-.4 t} + \cos(t))$, on the right sides of two of the equations.

Then you don't need to solve the differential equations (which you did wrong in any case), just use the superposition principle.  If $y_1'(t) + 9.7 y_1(t) = f(t)$ and $y_2'(t) + 9.7 y_2(t) = 0$, what is $(p y_1'(t) + q y_2'(t)) + 9.7 (p y_1(t) + q y_2(t))$?  If $y_1(0) = 0$ and $y_2(0) = 1$, what is $p y_1(0) + q y_2(0)$?

Comment: I fixed the equation.  This is all I was given on the superposition principle: The superposition principle says:
If y1[t] solves
       y'[t]+r y[t]=f[t]    with y[0]=p 
and if y2[t] solves
       y'[t]+r y[t]=g[t]  with y[0]=q
then
       y3[t]=y1[t]+y2[t] 
solves
       y'[t]+r y[t]=f[t]+g[t] with y[0]=p+q.  I dont understand how you get py1'(t) + qy2'(t) in the equation.

Comment: How do I get $p y_1'(t) + q y_2'(t)$?  If $y_3(t) = p y_1(t) + q y_2(t)$, then $y_3'(t) = p y_1'(t) + q y_2'(t)$.  Anyway, just use the superposition principle exactly as you stated it.  In this case $r = 9.7$, $f(t) = e^{-0.4t} \cos(t)$, $p = 0$, ...

Comment: Oh okay but isn't p = 0, q = 1? The 3 in the y3[t] equation is really throwing me off. I can find the solutions to y1[t] and y2[t].  So if I plug in those solutions into the y3[t] and y3'[t] can't I solve for p and t?

Comment: Actually you have two different $p$'s and $q$'s, which makes things confusing.  Let me restate the superposition principle with better notation.  If $y_1(t)$ solves $y'(t) + r y(t) = f(t)$ with $y(0) = a$ and $y_2(t)$ solves $y'(t) + r y(t) = g(t)$ with $y(0) = b$, then $y_3(t) = p y_1(t) + q y_2(t)$ solves $y'(t) + r y(t) = p f(t) + q g(t)$ with $y(0) = p a + q b$.

Comment: oh, so is it simply just p = 3 and q = 0 if y1(t) solves y′[t]+9.7y[t]=e−0.4tcos[t]?

Comment: @riotburn: no, because you need to also fit the initial condition.